# When implementing a Sonos Music API, how do I get a menu listing "collection" items, to display a "Play All" button?

Tags: sonos

### What I'm trying to achieve

I want to display the same "Play All" menu item I get when listing tracks (menus with `itemType=trackList`) for menus of other `itemType`s e.g. Playlists. Is that possible?

So for example, representing each menu as a nested list, I want:

- Collection 1

  - Play All <---- I don't get this one!
  - Playlist 1

    - Play All <-- I get this
    - Track 1
    - Track 2
    - ...
  - Playlist 2

    - Play All <-- I get this
    - Track 1
    - Track 1
  - ...

It's fine if this behaviour is not possible, but I just wanted to double-check.

### What the docs say

According to the [Sonos API docs](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/83), you can make other itemTypes playable by setting `canPlay=true`. In fact, it specifically mentions my use case:

> The canPlay flag is used to indicate that the collection can be queued up for playback in its entirety. In order to accomplish this, the client will call getMetadata passing in a Boolean parameter “recursive” set to true. This will return a flattened list of all mediaItem elements in the collection. **For example, “canPlay” might be true for a collection that represents a playlist of tracks**...

When I set `canPlay=true` I'm able to press and hold on the Collection in the prior menu, and have a menu popup that let's me play everything that way, but I don't get an actual "Play All" icon in the subsequent menu. Is that intended, or is there any way to display the "Play All" icon?

The [SMAPI itemTypes page](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/286) says:

> a mediaCollection of itemType trackList with a canEnumerate = true will enable the "All Tracks" node once you browse into the container, as shown below

Is that the only `itemType` that this will work for?

### My `getMetadata` Responses

In case it's useful, here's my `getMetadata` responses:

1. `getMetadata` call that displays the menu containing the Collection:

   ```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
         <getMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <getMetadataResult>
               <index>0</index>
               <count>10</count>
               <total>10</total>

               ...

               <mediaCollection>
                  <id>collections:134</id>
                  <itemType>collection</itemType>
                  <displayType>standardView</displayType>
                  <title>Collection 1</title>
                  <summary>Collection 1 Summary</summary>
                  <canPlay>true</canPlay>
                  <albumArtURI>https://path/to/album_art.jpg</albumArtURI>
               </mediaCollection>

               ...

            </getMetadataResult>
         </getMetadataResponse>
      </soap:Body>
       </soap:Envelope>
   ```
2. `getMetadata` call that lists the Collection's Playlists:

   ```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
         <getMetadataResponse xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <getMetadataResult>
               <index>0</index>
               <count>1</count>
               <total>1</total>
               <mediaCollection>
                  <id>collections:134:playlists:506</id>
                  <itemType>trackList</itemType>
                  <displayType>standardView</displayType>
                  <title>Playlist 1</title>
                  <summary>Playlist 1 summary</summary>
                  <canPlay>true</canPlay>
                  <albumArtURI>http://path/to/album_art.jpg</albumArtURI>
               </mediaCollection>
            </getMetadataResult>
         </getMetadataResponse>
      </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
   ```

Comment: Hi Rob, it seems you're getting to a good point with this. we'd need someone knowledgeable about this for a consultancy asap. would you be available? if ok plz let me know via chat or alessandro@dinahmoe.com

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to display is the "All Songs" node at the top of a collection of tracks. As you mention, setting "canPlay" equal to true will cause a "Play All" node to be displayed, and this should work for any mediaCollection regardless of container type. Similarly, setting "canEnumerate" to true should result in the "All Tracks" node being displayed at the the top of a container for any mediaCollection. There is unfortunately no way to display a Play all button at the top of a container.

Comment: Hi Allison, thanks for your response. I am indeed trying to display the "All Songs" node at the top of a container/collection of items. I refer to it as "Play All" above because that's the text that displays in the Sonos iPhone app for this item.

You say that this should work for any `mediaCollection`, regardless of container type (by setting `canPlay=true`), but this is not my experience. I only am able to get the "Play All" node showing in the menu when `itemType=trackList`. For other `itemTypes` e.g. `collection`, `other`, `container` etc, I do not see this node in the menu.

Comment: Is it possible that it is not shown for other `itemType`s in the iPhone app? Can you point me to an example of it working for a different Music Service perhaps?

Comment: Hi Rob, there shouldn't be any itemType level restrictions here and I unfortunately can't think of any other production services currently implementing this particular functionality. Looking above, it does not appear that you are specifically setting  canEnumerate to true - I would try this to start. One other thing to note, when the "Play All" node is added to the queue,  the player will send recursive is equal to true, and the results of the container will need to be returned as a flat list.